# Datapicker in material design

Tags: angularjs

Good day dear colleagues. I have dataPicker in MaterialDesign on my page. In my page I want see just part of dataPicker it is calendar like this. Anybody knows how to implement it?

I want to see this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Comment: You need to add some screenshots or images of your expected results. Also please add the code samples you have tried till now :)

Comment: I can't to add screenshot, because have not enough privilege =((

Comment: upload them on any free image share website, paste in the comment the link and we will edit your post to include them

Comment: Here is I want to see on my page: http://prntscr.com/8mhpgz.
Instead that : http://prntscr.com/8mhpo2

Comment: I have tried to display calendar without click on the input of dataPicker.
Help me.

Comment: Max, images added, just approve the edit. Also please provide some code snapshots related to this date picker

Comment: I didn't have any code. I just copy name of tag on this site: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.datepicker  and insert tag "md-datepicker" on my page like this-> http://prntscr.com/8mhu3a

Comment: show us the html page code. You can edit your post to add the code there, or use plunkr to create a demo of your code.

Comment: Btw, you can try to use the bootstrap datepicker, that one has the option to display the inline calendar. Demo here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo with bootstrap and angularjs with inline date picker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7pnPeudbgTY3hd2SNATA?p=preview

The important part is to include in html:

- script related to ui-bootstrap-tpls, in demo it is called `angular-ui-bootstrap.js`
- to inject into your module, this bootstrap - in demo this is done by `angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);`
- have the bootstrap css included
- In html just add

:

```
   <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>
  </div>
```

- and in controller initialize dt model: `$scope.dt = new Date();`

Comment: Thanks you for help. I hope it's help me.

Comment: Anybody have a propose?

Comment: Not really sure what do you mean? Is the solution above not working for you?

Comment: It is working. But I prefer to use exactly Material Design.